# Converting SQL query into LINQ - not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

The SQL query I'm trying to convert is:

```
select p.PhoneNumber_Id, p.State, p.Created
from PhoneNumberServiceItems p
join PhoneNumbers on p.PhoneNumber_Id = PhoneNumbers.Id
inner join (
    select PhoneNumber_Id, max(Created) as MaxDate
    from PhoneNumberServiceItems
    group by PhoneNumber_Id
) tm on p.PhoneNumber_Id = tm.PhoneNumber_Id and p.Created = tm.MaxDate
where PhoneNumbers.NumberRangeId = {Id}
```

And the LINQ code I've ended up with is below, however this isn't working:

```
 var res =
        from serviceItems in _db.PhoneNumberServiceItems
        join nums in _db.PhoneNumbers on serviceItems.PhoneNumber_Id equals nums.Id
        where nums.NumberRangeId == id
        join serviceGroup in (from ps in _db.PhoneNumberServiceItems
                      group ps by ps.PhoneNumber_Id into numGroup

                      //join tm in _db.PhoneNumbers on psg.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber_Id equals tm.Id
                      select new
                      {
                          NumId = numGroup.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber_Id,
                          MaxDate = numGroup.Max(i => i.Created)
                      }) on new { PNId = serviceItems.PhoneNumber_Id, serviceCreated = serviceItems.Created } equals new { PNId = serviceGroup.NumId, serviceCreated = serviceGroup.MaxDate }
        select new
        {
            State = serviceItems.State,
            NumId = serviceGroup.NumId,
            Created = serviceGroup.MaxDate
        };
```

I'm aware my LINQ is wrong, but I can't put my finger on what it is I'm doing differently. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This is the compiled SQL generated from the LINQ

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
[Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project4].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM   [dbo].[PhoneNumberServiceItems] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PhoneNumbers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PhoneNumber_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
    (SELECT 
        MAX([Extent5].[Created]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[PhoneNumberServiceItems] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE [Project3].[PhoneNumber_Id] = [Extent5].[PhoneNumber_Id]) AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Distinct1].[PhoneNumber_Id] AS [PhoneNumber_Id], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent4].[PhoneNumber_Id] AS [PhoneNumber_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[PhoneNumberServiceItems] AS [Extent4]
            WHERE [Distinct1].[PhoneNumber_Id] = [Extent4].[PhoneNumber_Id]) AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent3].[PhoneNumber_Id] AS [PhoneNumber_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[PhoneNumberServiceItems] AS [Extent3]
        )  AS [Distinct1]
    )  AS [Project3] ) AS [Project4] ON ([Extent1].[PhoneNumber_Id] = [Project4].[C1]) AND ([Extent1].[Created] = [Project4].[C2])
WHERE [Extent2].[NumberRangeId] = {id}
```

Comment: How is it 'wrong' ?  Is there a compile error?  Is the wrong data being retrieved?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. When I look at the complied SQL from the LINQ query, it's doing a much more intensive query than the one I've written above. I'll edit my post and add it in.

Comment: Why don't you just run the SQL?

Comment: I'd just like to know if there's a better way of writing the LINQ code that replicates what I've got in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is linq equivalent of your query.

```
var res = from s in PhoneNumberServiceItems
          join p in PhoneNumbers on s.PhoneNumber_Id equals p.Id
          join tm in ( from p1 in PhoneNumberServiceItems 
                       group p1 by p1.PhoneNumber_Id into p_g 
                       select new {PhoneNumber_Id = p_g.Key,MaxDate = p_g.Max(i=> i.Created)  }  )
                    on new {Created = s.Created, PhoneNumber_Id = s.PhoneNumber_Id} 
                         equals new { Created = tm.MaxDate, PhoneNumber_Id = tm.PhoneNumber_Id} 
            where p.NumberRangeId == {Id}
            select new
                    {
                        s.PhoneNumber_Id,
                        s.State,
                        s.Created
                    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following which is much simpler :

```
 var res = (from nums in _db.PhoneNumbers.Where(x => NumberRangeId == id)
        join  serviceItems in _db.PhoneNumberServiceItems on nums.PhoneNumber_Id equals serviceItems.Id
        select new {serviceItems = serviceItems, nums = nums})
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.serviceItems.Created)
        .GroupBy(x => x.nums.PhoneNumber_Id)
        .Select(x => x.First())
        .Select(x => new {Id = x.nums.PhoneNumber_Id, state = x.serviceItems.State,  maxDate = x.serviceItems.Created})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the SQL generated is much simplier, however it doesn't seem to bring back any data now. The LINQ query looks like it's doing the right selection though.

Comment: I switched the query around a little bit.  If it still doesn't work remove the WHERE and see if you get results.

Answer (score 1):

```
var recentPhoneNos=  from psi in _db.PhoneNumberServiceItems 
                    group psi by psi .PhoneNumber_Id into psiTemp
                    select new {
                       PhoneNumber_Id = psiTemp.Key,
                       MaxDate = psiTemp.Max(i=> i.Created)
                    };


var res=from serviceItems in _db.PhoneNumberServiceItems
        join nums in _db.PhoneNumbers on serviceItems.PhoneNumber_Id equals nums.Id
        join serviceGroup in recentPhoneNos on nums.Id equals serviceGroup .PhoneNumber_Id 
        where nums.NumberRangeId == id && serviceGroup.MaxDate 
        select new {
                    State = serviceItems.State,
                    NumId = serviceGroup.NumId,
                    Created = serviceGroup.MaxDate
       } ;
```